# Enable Word (docx) document track changes without Interop

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there a way and how to turn on Track Changes feature for MS Word document (docx) without using Interop assembly? I know that it is supposed to be done with XML, but how? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, `outputDocument` is of type `WordprocessingDocument` AKA `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument`.

```
outputDocument.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.Append(new TrackRevisions());
```

EDIT:

you might wanna check first if Settings is `null`. The `Settings` class has a fully qualified name `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Settings`.

Comment: OK, so I opened the file with `WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, true);`. Next, I used your code to set Track Changes. Should I save the file in the end? How does all that work? Thanks.

Comment: @Boris, do not take it the wrong way, but you really should read up on OpenXML (plenty of tutorials online, it is really useful). Just close the document with `close()` and you should be all set. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.close.aspx